# Version control with hooks, migration and bash

Tags: php, git, drupal-7, drush

I'm trying to find a fine solution for migration control betweem local wamp and server lamp involving git and Drupal.

I've already found a nice solution for migration control with CodeIgniter thanks to the [Migration](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html) class. Then I can utilize the `post-receive` hook and just run `php path/to/codeigniter/index.php migrate/index` and it simply updates the database design along with the files.

However from what I've seen so far with Drupal, this is a bit trickier. I am currently considering to in some manner store Drush commands for enabling new modules and such. The idea would then be to have a system similiar to [Migration](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html) which I simply run with `post-receive` and the new modules gets enabled through `drush en -y new_module` whos command is saved somewhere.

The ideal flow illustrated here:

[image: Ideal flow]

What I suppose I would need to complete this flow is to have the bash script executed by `post-receive`, fetch some file named for instance `001.txt` inside a directoy named `drush_commands`, and based on a variable I have saved in a file mentioned in `.gitignore`, execute the files with a number higher then the saved value, then set the value to the highest number amongst the executed files.

### Question

However I'm not sure how to and if it's even possible to do this with bash scripts ideally. Is this approach an ideal one and how would the bash script work, or do you know any better way to have the same modules enabled (and other drush things) on both my local wamp and the server upon `push`ing?

**Bonus question:** Could I use this approach to handle changes to field data, content type and such? I have some trouble grasping exactly how I can sync the overall structure between local and live version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible both in theory and practice although I wouldn't attempt to complete it entirely using a post-receive hook.

The ideal solution would be to have a CI server for example Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/) sat listening with a job configured to handle migrations and use the post-receive hook to trigger this job via either the CLI interface or a cURL request. This takes the onus of a build away from Git (where it doesn't belong) and into CI (where it does).

There are a number of decent CI solutions out there, both free and proprietary which will handle all of this for you with some basic configuration.

The configured job when triggered, checks out your repo (based on a branch you specify) into its own workspace directory and can then call a script to build it as an application.

```
# post-receive hook
curl http://my.ci-server.local/job/drush_command/buildWithParameters?&GITBRANCH=$GIT_BRANCH&delay=0
```

- `my.ci-server.local` Your locally installed CI server installation
- `drush_command` would be the name of your job
- `GIT_BRANCH` is the name of the branch to build (default develop???)

Within the CI job you would then have a script which executes steps similar to the following:

```
# GitIgnore file
savedValue:0001

# bash script
savedValue=$(cat $WORKSPACE/.gitignore | grep 'savedValue' | cut -d: -f2);
newValue=$(savedValue);
for file in $(ls $WORKSPACE/drush_commands); do

    currentValue=$(echo $file | cut -d. -f1);
    if [ $currentValue -gt $savedValue ] ; then

        drush en -y "${currentValue}.txt}";
        if [ $currentValue > $newValue ] ; then
            newValue=$currentValue;
        fi
    fi
done

sed -i '' "s/savedValue.*/savedValue:$newValue/" $WORKSPACE/.gitignore;
```

You could further extend this to handle changes to data by having a separate script called after the loop which looks for other scripts to execute which would then pick up the changes to carry out from a separate directory?

Couple of points:

- I wouldn't add the saved value to the .gitignore file - this isn't really the place for it. Use a separate configuration file (e.g. `conf/last_enabled`) for this kind of information.
- The loop isn't going to work terribly well if you have files within the `drush_commands` dir which are not named '001.txt 002.txt' etc. You'll have to filter around these to make sure you're getting the latest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Saving to `.gitignore` isn't intended. I meant to save to a file mentioned in `.gitignore` to make it work between versions. Why exactly shouldn't I run this through `post-receive`? It feels like the most logical thing to do.

Comment: It is entirely feasible to carry out all this within a post-receive hook (the snippet I supplied could be used in that capacity) it's not really what they are designed to do and for the sake of clarity it's better to maintain a separation of concerns. You're effectively building the app - this is the job of a CI server - You indicate that the hook should check out the code, If something goes wrong during this operation you could potentially pollute or even destroy your central repository.

Comment: I'll have CI servers in mind, but since everything works well for me atm it won't be now. The last line's a regexp replace, right? What's the difference between `-gt` and `>`? Do you know any site that teaches these commands?

Comment: Yes the last line uses the 'sed' (stream editor) command in bash to replace the line with a new value. The difference between -gt and > is shell internal. `-gt` is for numerical comparison. Have a look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html for examples.